# Factory still not registered after trying solutions provided

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I am trying to write an Rspec test for the first time, my model test worked out fine, but I have problems with my controller test. Which seems weird. For my model test, I'm following the example from: https://gist.github.com/kyletcarlson/6234923

I am given the infamous `Factory not registered:` error. The log is below:

```
1) ProductsController POST create when given all good parameters
     Failure/Error: post :create, product: attributes_for(valid_product)
     ArgumentError:
       Factory not registered: #<Product:0x007fc47275a330>
     # ./spec/controllers/products_controller_spec.rb:12:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I have tried solutions given by others and now my files look like this:

`Gemfile`

```
group :test, :development do
  gem 'shoulda'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
end
```

`rails_helper.rb`

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require 'spec_helper'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'factory_girl_rails'
...
RSpec.configure do |config|
  ...
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
end
```

`/spec/factories/products.rb`

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :product do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "test_name_#{n}" }
    price "1.50"
    description "Test Description"
  end
end
```

`/spec/controllers/products_controller_spec.rb`

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe ProductsController do

  let(:valid_product) { create(:product) }
  let(:invalid_product) { create(:product, name: nil, price: 0, description: test_description) }

  describe "POST create" do

    context 'when given all good parameters' do
      before(:each){
        post :create, product: attributes_for(valid_product)

      }

      it { expect(assigns(:product)).to be_an_instance_of(Product) }
      it { expect(response).to have_http_status 200 }
    end

  end

end
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.
*Updated to include factories details, that was already implemented before question was posed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line

```
    post :create, product: attributes_for(valid_product)
```

You are calling `attributes_for` passing `valid_product` which is an actual instance of `Product`, hence the error message.

I suspect you intended to write

```
    post :create, product: attributes_for(:product)
```

Comment: `post :create, product: valid_product.attributes` does what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify factory separately. Create `spec/factories/products.rb` with content:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :product do
    name 'My awesome product'
    price  100
    description 'Just a simple awesome product'
    # add there attributes you need 
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry, but I have already done so. I forgot to include that in my question. I have updated my question.